# Pay u money Invalid amount error

Tags: postman, payumoney

I am trying to sending all the inputs from postman using the production link but i am getting response `"Sorry! We were unable to process your payment invalid-amount "`.

These are the inputs am sending from the postman

```
{
"Key":"XXXXXX",
"txnid":"abc123",
"amount":"1000.0",
"productinfo ":"Product 1",
"firstname ":"abc",
"email ":"abc@gmail.com",
"phone":"9090909090",
"surl ":"https://www.google.co.in/",
"furl ":"https://www.google.co.in/",
"hash(Checksum)":"52E715A74C226312B081E91E21E4DA1B179A55F750C330386BBF960204A196ABBCA656FA894A60D5F32796CF4BE67D2DEF9B4AD9E81562118A2C30A94B57C9DD"
"service_provider":"payu_paisa"
}
```

But am getting

> "Sorry! We were unable to process your payment invalid-amount ".

Comment: Isn't currency is required? Should the `amount` be text and not `"amount": 1000.0` (no quotes around the number)?

Answer (score 5):

Try to send data to payu as "x-www-form-urlencoded", that solved this particular issue

Comment: The endpoint doesnot accept JSON data, but it accepts form-url-encoded or plain POST form.

Comment: Still not working for me. Getting `Invalid amount`. Any other solutions??

Comment: @pragyan please mark the answer as "accepted", so that we can close this.